# Download all available Latitude and Longitude From any web page of Map

Tags: php

Hi Actually I want that is there any tool or any process through which i extract all the latitudes and longitudes which are available on any map web page.

Suppose i open a web page where there is approx 10 - 20 places are tagged and i want to export all in one download click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this task you can use a scriptable browser ( like a [SlimerJS](https://slimerjs.org/) or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) ).

Comment: Thanks... Leo Komarov

Answer (score 0):

It's highly likely that map data is sent to you through JSON responses and you can easily extract the data from there. However, this question is far too open and you have not told us which provider you're referring to when it comes to the maps.

Further explanation would be great, then I can edit this post with some sort of example.